# How to emulate Java class with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I want to emulate a given type from a third-party library (GAE),

a Java class that is not supported by GWT:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt;
```

How do I emulate this class so GWT will support it? Where should I put the `GeoPt.java` file in my GWT app?

I cannot put it in the client path the packaging is different that my app. What could be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further I assume, you have a module com.example.Example.gwt.xml .

I think you have two options. You can create a separate module, eg. AppEngine.gwt.xml, which source tag set to "api" and you put it into  on com.google.appengine level. Then, you module need to inherit it  - `<inherits name="com.google.appengine.AppEngine"/>`. It can be even in the same project - one project might have multiple modules.

Another approach is when you eg. want to reimplement a class only in GWT, while use same one in pure Java. Then in your module you create  tag which points to a folder that will be a kind of root for a replaced classes. So, in your module you add `<super-source path="appengine"/>` and then you would put the class to `com.example.appengine.com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt`. You can read more on this at [Organizing Projects](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html), go to *Overriding one package implementation with another* section